Manifest.json not updating properly in iOS
My React app is a PWA that dynamically changes the manifest.json content based on URL (this is made by triggering a useEffect once data has been fetched from the API, and generating a blob with the new manifest.json content, replacing the original with setAttribute).
Those changes are perfectly shown in any Android device, and (like in the example below) the name changes properly, but on iOS (Safari), saving the PWA will only show the default name of the original manifest.json and not update it with new content. Same goes for other manifest.json props like start_url and images.
Default manifest.json
{
  "short_name": "My Webapp",
}

index.html
<link rel="manifest" id="manifest-json" href="./manifest.json"/>

Main.tsx
        // triggered when data is successfully fetched and stored
        let name = fetchedData.name
        let dynamicManifest = {
            "short_name": `${name}`,
            // ...more data for manifest.json
        }

        const stringManifest = JSON.stringify(dynamicManifest);
        const blob = new Blob([stringManifest], { type: "application/json" });
        const manifestURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        document.querySelector("#manifest-json")?.setAttribute("href", manifestURL);
   

Is that an iOS limitation?
The manifest seems to be properly updated when I check on Safari (MacOS).
